# Python requests not returning proper data

Tags: python, python-requests

I am doing a scrapping project and I am having an issue, using python requests I am able to log-in in the website and grab the tokens to be sent afterward, problem comes after. Sending the proper tokens doing a post to gram the info of a table (that should appear with the post), but the post returns not the data but an HTML without the data.

[image]
Image of the response from the post on the web.

[image]
image of the response through python requests.

what could be causing this? and how to harvest the data, I am doing the appropriate post and giving the cookies and credentials.

edit with code

```py
def login():
    credentials = file_manager.file_manager.get_credentials()
    print(credentials)

    headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;'
        }
    
    session = requests.session()

    session.headers.update(headers)

    r = session.get(credentials[0])

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    verificationToken = (soup.find(attrs={'name':'__RequestVerificationToken'}).attrs['value'])

    parameters = {
        "__RequestVerificationToken":str(verificationToken),
        "versao":"6",
        "Email":credentials[1],
        "Password":credentials[2],
        "ReturnUrl":""
    }

    r = session.post(url,params=parameters, headers=headers)
    r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = session.get(url,headers=headers)

    parameters = {
            parameter:parameter,
        }

    r = session.post(url, headers=headers)

    f = open('response.html','w', encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(r.text)
```

Comment: `what could be causing this?` javascript

Comment: yeah but I need to grab the data, so any ways to do this in requests? or I will need another language or framework like selenium? Requests would be best however I am open.

Comment: @Flari did you set user agent or some other header to your request?

Comment: yes, these here

        `headers = {
            'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;'
            }`

Comment: `requests` is just an http client. If the data isn't returned by the http request, then you're going to need to investigate other tools. A lot of websites using javascript to populate a page after the initial document has been loaded; to scrape these websites, you need to use a real browser that is able to execute the javascript. Selenium is one option; there are also other tools that wrap a browser in some form of automation.

Comment: As others have pointed out it is likely the table you're looking for is constructed using AJAX. Look at the HTML you're getting. You'll probably see that it is using Javascript. In which case you'll need to use Selenium or something similar. Also, scraping HTML to extract data is fragile and expensive. Investigate whether there is a proper API for fetching the data you want (HTML web pages is not a proper API).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out on what to do.

Add `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` to the header for the POST
and use `data=` instead of `params=` for the request.